# Chrome driver with Selenium VBA

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Weird, after getting answers from here for years on so many topics, this time I cannot find the solution to the problem, therfore I became a member finally.

I have Selenium set up & functioning in Access, I know everywhere I've looked says it's for Excel but all appears ok in Access. The problem appears to be having the correct driver, this is why I need help.

My Chromedriver is 121.0.6167.85 (latest from I can tell but my browser is 121.0.6167.161

So I'm asking from those with more experience running this, is this the correct driver?

On https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads I am advised "If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer, please consult the Chrome for Testing availability dashboard. This page provides convenient JSON endpoints for specific ChromeDriver version downloading."
The above as a link which takes me here https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing

The only similar driver is 121.0.6167.160 but this is not avaialble as yet, however 122.0.6261.29 is available.

When I run the script ith Access with 121.0.6167.85 (my current driver) I get the following message:

Run-time error 33
SessionNotCreatedError
Session not dreated: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(Session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location c:\program files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so Chromedriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
(Driver info: chromedriver=121.0.6167.85

Although the browser fires up ok, I can't do anything with it as this VBA error has held up the script.

All the above ONLY happens after I try with my default profile, Chrome when it opens, excepts my profile so the profile selection appears ok.

WITHOUT the profile selected, the browser works just fine & I don't have any driver issues, but it no use as it won't store cookies.

I am trying to collect info from Ebay with this process & Ebay uses a confirmation code via txt to login & thats just a pain.

Anyone get any advice on this please?

Although the browser fires up ok, I can't do anything with it as this VBA error has held up the script.

All the above ONLY happens after I try with my default profile, Chrome when it opens, excepts my profile so the profile selection appears ok.

WITHOUT the profile selected, the browser works just fine & I don't have any driver issues, but it no use as it won't store cookies.

I am trying to collect info from Ebay with this process & Ebay uses a confirmation code via txt to login & thats just a pain.

Anyone get any advice on this please?

Comment: I have the same issue, I've given up and used Edge webdriver ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

i faced  the same issue didn't get any resolution of it still wait from google to get the chrome driver of the same version.

Comment: Thanks, how long have you been waiting for this? Is there no other option? I did read you can restore earlier version of chrome browser, maybe that's the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

You might download chromedriver from here:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

or downgrade your chrome browser:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7125792?hl=en

Comment: Not sure if the way forward is downgrading the browser & I say that sincerly. Looks like latest Chrome Browser for testing is run as a seperate browser to our normal chrome browser. So as I understand it now, Selenium runs all testting upgrades of both browser & driver, problem appears to be Selenium basic. I want to run this from Access using Selenium light and that is my stumbling block. Running from Python or Javascript ect does have options available. This is how I understand it at this present time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows you can download this:

win 32: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.85/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip

win 64: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.85/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue but i wasn't patient enough so I installed Dev version of the Google chrome

https://www.google.com/chrome/dev/

then use driver for dev channel

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#dev

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved using WebDriver Manager.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/

Just test and apply your source code.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, as a newby at somewhat in the dark here, can Selenium Manager be run along side Selenium Basic

Answer (score 0):

you can use webdriver-manager it will resolve your issue

pip install webdriver-manager

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the version 121.0.6167.160 is not represented on the https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ but it is available by the direct link:

linux64:
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/121.0.6167.160/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip

win32:
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/121.0.6167.160/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip

win64:
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/121.0.6167.160/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip